# I need to put a bunch of bunch of dictionaries into a tuple, with a label

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, nltk

The end goal is to get `classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(-placeholder-)` to run.

As it stands, I have:

```
for i in range(0, len(p)):
   .....
   qq = add_lexical_features(bi_dist, feature_vector)
```

`qq` here is my dictionary. Now, I need to add the word `"positive"` and combine it with the `qq` that is generating from the next run through the loop. Problem is, I don't really know how tuples work. Thanks.

Here is an example of one qq dictionary WITH the label ("neg") added.

({'unigram:long': 1, 'unigram:ve_2': 0.003372681281618887, 'unigram:beholder_1': 0.0016863406408094434, 'unigram:good_3': 0.00505902192242833, 'unigram:unit_1': 0.0016863406408094434, 'unigram:mireniamu_1': 0.0016863406408094434}, 'neg')]

Comment: Can you give us sample `qq` and sample tuple to add to and what the expected output is?

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful. What do you want your tuple to look like? The syntax for Python tuples is very simple, you just put the stuff you want inside parenthesis. E.g., tup = (1, 2, 3) will create a tuple, tup, containing 1, 2, and 3. You can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Sorry, it was quite long so I wasn't sure if I should add it in. Its there now.

Comment: Can you cut it down a bit? Maybe only retain the first 3-4 entries just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Done, so I have a bunch of those, without the label as they are generated by my loop. I just need to add the label and put them all into one big tuple so the classifier can read them.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in python are pretty straightforward to use and access. For most uses they work just like lists.

```
# create some simple tuples.
a = ('A', 1)
b = ('B', 2)
# Reading tuples. Access the elements with []
print a[0]    # 'A'
print b[1]    # 2
print len(a)  # 2

# tuples can be stored in your dict
qq['some-key'] = a
qq['another-key'] = b

print qq['some-key'][0]
```

Comment: Sorry, could you relate this a little more specifically to my question? I don't need to store a tuple in the dictionary, I need to change my dictionaries into one tuple.

Comment: I don't understand this part 'change dictionaries into one tuple'. Do you want to take all the key value pairs in the dict and convert them into tuples?